# How to contain the smell of truffle spice?

Tags: storage-method, spices, storage, smell

From our trip to Venice, Italy we brought home some truffle spice. It says "truffle powder" on the small container and mainly consists of salt, flour, truffle and dried mushrooms.

It smells delicious, but **very** intensive. A very small amount of powder is enough to add a nice and subtle taste to any meal. Too much could easily ruin it.

When I first opened the packaging, the smell immediately struck me. After using it for the first time, I stored it in a ziploc bag. After a day, the whole kitchen smelled like truffle as soon as I opened the spice cabinet. Since a sealable plastic bag did not seem to do the job, I took a small airtight container with the perfect size to fit it in and returned it into my cabinet.

This was some days ago, and in spite of regularly opening all windows during the day, the smell hits you when you enter the apartment. How can this spice possibly smell so intense? It is locked airtight! What else can I do?

Comment: what type of 'airtight' container did you use?  Most plastics aren't really airtight.  (I've had asafoetida triple bagged, and run into the same issues that you describe)

Comment: @Joe It is a Lock&Lock-type box with a rubber seal.

Comment: I'm not sure if smells will permeate through a rubber seal or not.  I had to move my asafoetida to a glass container.

Comment: Might it help to keep it in the freezer?

Comment: @Megha I really don't want to try that. I'd rather not have my freezer smell like that.

Comment: @Joe Good suggestion! Consider writing it as an answer. I am struggling to find a glass container that is not grossly oversized and has a glass lid.

Comment: I know it worked for my issue, but I don't know about truffles.  If it works, go ahead and write up what you used.  (I keep empty spice jars/tins, so I can put spices I buy from bulk bins into them)

Answer (score 1):

I make tiny pouches, sousvide and then store them in a vacuum container. It works well. Takes some time to do but when you make tiny portions the rest will stay very fresh .In case you have some left in the little pouch you can put it in a small bottle with a good olive oil and use as a dressing over fried eggs or mushrooms or veg or potatoes or a deli salad...your choice. Vacuum containers are very handy since you can reuse them every time and everything stays perfect. 
I even put them in the freezer myself and the freezer does not smell at all.